# How to import/download already existing cloudflare resource(s) using terraform?

Tags: terraform, cloudflare

If I have existing cloudflare settings (using web console), how to import/download existing cloudflare resource(s),e.g DNS records using terraform?
So, I could use it as a starting point to modify/update it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Each Terraform resource has an example of importing existing data. For example, the [record import](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/cloudflare/cloudflare/latest/docs/resources/record#import)

```
$ terraform import cloudflare_record.default ae36f999674d196762efcc5abb06b345/d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cf-terraforming](https://github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming) tool to terraforming existing CF resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your steps will look like this:

1. Describe a Terraform configuration that contains the resources you want to manage with Terraform.
2. Initialize the created configuration using `terraform init` and after (this is convenient) quickly get the addresses of the resources that you need for import using `terraform plan`.
3. Next, you need to get the IDs of existing resources, they will also be required for import. For the Cloudflare Zone resource, this is easy to do, just refer to [this instruction](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/basic-tasks/find-account-and-zone-ids/), for other resources, for example, for Cloudflare record you will either need to use [cf-terraforming](https://github.com/cloudflare/cf-terraforming#importing-with-terraform-state) or [Cloudflare API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#dns-records-for-a-zone-list-dns-records).
4. Import your resources using the `terraform import RESOURCE_ADDRESS RESOURCE_ID` command.

Another way is to delete your resources and recreate them with Terraform instead of importing them. This can make your infrastructure unavailable for some time.

I highly recommend that you read these guides:

1. https://developers.cloudflare.com/terraform/advanced-topics/import-cloudflare-resources/.
2. https://github.com/alex-feel/terraform-cloudflare-zone/wiki/Migration (it is written for a module, but is equally applicable to "raw" resources).